# Soundcloud API get tracks force update

Tags: javascript, json, soundcloud

Hey I would like to know please how can I retrieve tracks from the [Soundcloud API](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks) and force it to be up to date and not from a cache please?

The issue I got is that I added **new** tags to the tracks on Soundcloud, and I want to get these using the API, but the API returns old results like the new tags that I added aren't exist, which means there is probably a cache and I don't see any kind of "update" parameter in the [documentations](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks) so I can't update the cache and it isn't reading the new tags.

Here's an example of my code:

```
SC.get('/users/[user-ID#-goes-here]/tracks', {
  tags: 'test'
}, function(tracks) {
  console.log(tracks);
});
```

or simply by visiting the next url:

```
http://api.soundcloud.com/users/[user-ID#-goes-here]/tracks?client_id=[client-ID-goes-here]&limit=15&tags=test
```

Is there any parameter to force an update to the cache please?

Comment: AFAIK, SoundCloud API doesn't offer real-time updates.

Comment: @AdamAzad Thanks, do you may know for how long they catching the results please?